# Nth-child selector in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, css-float

I have this page structure

```
<div class="pictures-page">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>   


</div>
```

All elements here are floating left, what i need is that every second picture element float right?

I have tried with div:nth-child(odd) but then all picture are floating right, i need every second picture to float right? Is there solution with simple CSS??

Answer (score 0):

the following does what you are asking for :

```
.pictures-page *:nth-child(4n+1) img{float:right;}
.pictures-page div:nth-child(2n+1){clear:left;}
```

but I'm guessing you are really wanting are the images alternating at the left and right edges of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
html, body{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body * {box-sizing:inherit;}

.pictures-page{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}

.pictures-page img{max-height:150px width:auto;}
.pictures-page .row:nth-child(2n+1) .col-md-6:nth-child(1){float:right;text-align:right;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="pictures-page">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="/assets/components/phpthumbof/cache/27.71c8b506d35dd3f2df6e61c93e7bb2973.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6">TEXT</div>   
</div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```